# golang FileServer set directory

Tags: go, fileserver

I have a `Golang` Shell with a FileServer function that I want to be able to change the src directory.
Here is what I have:

```
func Server() {
    wdir, _ := os.Getwd()
    m := http.NewServeMux()
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(wdir))
    m.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", fs))
    s := http.Server{Addr: ":8000", Handler: m}
    m.HandleFunc("/shutdown", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        s.Shutdown(context.Background())
    })
    if err := s.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Finished")
}
```

I have it this way so that if I get to `shutdown`, the FileServer closes.
But no matter from what path I launch `Server()`, the path remains always the same.

So if from the shell I `cd` into another folder and launch `Server()`, I will still get the files from the directory where the executable is.

What I want is that if I run the shell from `/home/user/Downloads/shell` and inside the shell I `cd` into `/opt`, the files to show in the server are the ones in `/opt`, not the ones in `/home/user/Downloads/shell`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to set it up so that the Server is started from the same directory where the shell is.

Comment: The behavior you're describing is exactly what you should be getting, assuming two things: you are executing a built binary, *not* using `go run`; and you're in the correct directory *before* starting your application.

Comment: I was using `go run`, perhaps that was the problem. Didn't know it could vary if I used `go run` instead of the built binary.

Comment: You should almost never use `go run`.

Comment: Why so? I didn't know it was such a bad idea. I am a newbie, so any important stuff is welcome

Comment: I built the binary and tried `cd`-ing before launching the server, I am still getting the default path..

Comment: Go is not a scripting language, it's meant to be compiled to binary and the binary executed; that's what `go run` does under the hood, creating a temporary binary and forking it. That forking can cause various issues. In your code, try printing `wdir` during the startup process and confirm it's what you're expecting.

Comment: printing `wdir` gives me the right directory, and I get the same result whether I use `go run` or `go build` and then execute the binary

Answer (score 0):

You can bring in the FileServer `path` as a flag and use that to create the FileServer.

```
http.FileServer(http.Dir(path + "/opt")).
```

Please check the flag [library](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) provided by go.

And in the terminal you can feed `pwd` into that flag value

Comment: I don't want it to always be `opt`, I want the Fileserver to serve files from the directory I'm in. Nevertheless, I tried with ```directory := flag.String("d", wdir, wdir)
 flag.Parse()
 m.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(*directory)))``` and didn't work either

Comment: Problem with flags is that I might want to redefine a flag, and that is not allowed. I might want to start a server in `/opt` first, then kill the server and start the server in `/home/user`. setting `directory := flag.String("d", wdir, "directory")` will set the correct directory, but I will not be able to set a new path to the server, which is what I want.